# How do I pass a JSON array to a JavaScript variable on my GSP page?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have the following Controller Action:

```
def doSomething() {
  [data: data as JSON]
}
```

On my GSP I can output the data params with:

```
${data}
```

Since data represents valid JSON I want to use it inside a JavaScript block on my GSP.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = [
            { Date: "2015-09-14", DayOfMonth: 14, Type: "Views", Amount: 0, y1: 10, }
           ];
</script>
```

To replace a hard coded JSON variable. I know I can do the replacement with Strings like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = "${data}";
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = "${raw(data)}";
</script>
```

The former works fine work primitive types like Strings but if I pass the JSON Array to the JavaScript variable it fails. When I print the content of the JavaScript data variable in the console I get:

```
[{&quot;Date&quot;:&quot;2015-09-13T22:00:00Z&quot;,&quot;DayOfMonth&quot;:14,&quot;Type&quot;:&quot;Views&quot;,&quot;Amount&quot;:1}]
```

**How do I pass a JSON array to a JavaScript variable on my GSP page?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an encoding problem that has yet to be resolved.

**Solution 1** - disable encoder locally

```
<g:applyCodec encodeAs="none">
    var data = ${data};
</g:applyCodec>
```

**Solution 2** - Affects the whole page

```
<%@page defaultCodec="none" %>
```

**Solution 3** - Use a custom tag

```
class MyTagLib {
    static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'none']

    def writeWithoutEncoding = {attrs ->
        out << attrs.input
    }
}
```

and in the GSP page:

```
var data = <g:writeWithoutEncoding input="${data}"/>;
```

References: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11829 and http://aruizca.com/how-to-render-json-properly-without-escaping-quotes-inside-a-gsp-script-tag/

Comment: You could add the solution of creating a taglib too.

Comment: Thanks, after your suggestion I added a third way that uses a custom tag.